# Coldfusion different Session timeout lengths

Tags: session, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

The website editors want a long period of login, and as the login relies on the session scope the session period is currently at 10 hours.

This is giving us poor performance on the front end. How can I best separate the two?

I have found one way to get it to work, but would like to consider alternate solutions, this will expire the session if it's not an admin user.

```
<cfif NOT StructKeyExists( session, "user" )>
<cfscript>
  StructDelete(cookie, 'cfid');
  StructDelete(cookie, 'cftoken');
  session.setMaxInactiveInterval(1);
</cfscript>
```

The website is quite old and uses Application.cfm, I have tried adding another Application.cfm, which 'includes' the first, for the administration area with it's own  but now each application gets confused over what cookie to create/use.

I have looked at resources such as

https://misterdai.wordpress.com/2010/06/15/cf-sessionstop-ending-a-cf-session/

and

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1847-explicitly-ending-a-coldfusion-session.htm

I even considered converting to Application.cfc, but this is time critical and there is some quirky legacy code in there I don't have time to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to separate the front end and admin as two different applications. 
Since you don't want to convert to Application.cfc (solution bellow), you can do it in your Application.cfm

```
<cfapplication name="ApplicationName"
sessionmanagement="Yes"
sessiontimeout="#CreateTimeSpan('0','4','0','0')#">
```

For Application.cfc

```
<cfset this.sessionManagement = true />
<cfset this.sessionTimeout = createTimeSpan( 0, 0, 5, 0 ) />
```

Comment: Since both Applications needed to use the same Application variables, I moved those to a new file application_variables.cfm - then I included that to both. When I included an Application file that already had a <application> defined, it caused some conflict.

Comment: Since the timeout is set only once for the application, can you reset it (increased) when the admin logs into the back end? Then you wouldn't have the overhead of two sessions, and wont have to manage two application.c** files.

Answer (score 1):

We have some pages where the user has to spend a lot of time editing which has the potential to have their sessions time out.  On those specific pages we keep the session alive by including another page which is in very small iframe. This page does a meta refresh at a specified interval.

We made this reuseable by writing two files.  The first one, PreventTimeout.cfm gets called like this:

```
<cfinclude template="path goes here/PreventTimeout.cfml">
```

It has this code:

```
<cfparam name="RefreshMinutes" default="15" type="integer">
<cfset RefreshSeconds = RefreshMinutes * 60>
<cfoutput>
<iframe height="1" width="1" 
src="path goes here /PreventTimeoutIFrameContents.cfm?
RefreshSeconds=#RefreshSeconds#">
</iframe>
</cfoutput>
```

The PreventTimeoutIFrameContents.cfm has the meta refresh code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using frames, you're welcome to this snippet of code. I have a frame on the left of the back end that has the navigation to cms modules (pages, reviews, etc).

[image]

In that left nav frame page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.location.replace('nav.cfm');
    },900000);
</script>
```

Every 15 minutes the navigation reloads. Which is half of the default 30 minutes session timer. Therefore the session does not expire while the cms backend is open.
Because only the left nav frame is being reloaded, the content frame (with an open text editor perhaps) is never overwritten. Changes are not lost.